# Join two select queries where result of one query is dependent on another query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two queries as below:

```
select column1, column2, column3, ....
from table1
where.... as T1

select count(*)
from table2
where column1 = T1.column1
```

Is it possible to combine both into one query

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can, as an American president once said:

```
select table1.column1, count(*)
from table1
join table2
on table1.column1 = table2.column1
group by table1.column1
```

will tell you how many elements you have in each `group`. If you need to `select` other values as well, then you will either have to aggregate by them as well, by putting them into the `group by` clause or use aggregate functions for them, like `group_concat` to put the values into a list separated by your separator.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way uses subqueries in the `select`:

```
select (select column1, column2, column3, ....
        from table1
        where....
       ) as T1,
       (select count(*)
        from table2
        where column1 = T1.column1
       ) as T2;
```